# ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I'm trying to set new values for a table that I have in my DB with ASP Classic. I am getting this error:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'
>
> Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested
>   name or ordinal.
>
> /Unirme.asp, línea 61 (rs3("IdFichas") = i)

I dont know why it happens since the column does exist in the table and the value I am passing to the DB is an int.

This is the part of my ASP code where it occurs the error:

```
    Set rs3 = server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

    SQL3 = "SELECT * FROM FichasTablero WHERE 0"    

    con.BeginTrans

    rs2.OPEN SQL2,con,2,3
    rs3.OPEN SQL2,con,2,3
    rs2.AddNew
    rs3.AddNew

    rs2("IdPartida") = IdPartida
    rs2("IdJugador") = IdJugador 
    rs2("Comidas_El") = 0
    rs2("Comidas_A_El") = 0

    dim i
    i = 0
    Response.Write(i & "-")

    For x = 1 To 2
        For y = 1 To 8
            i = i+1
            Response.Write(i & "-")
            rs3("IdPartida") = IdPartida
            rs3("IdFichas") = i
            rs3("IdPosicion") = x&y
            rs3("EstadoInicial") = 1
            rs3.Update
        Next
    Next

    For x = 7 To 8
        For y = 1 To 8
            i = i+1
            Response.Write(i & "-")
            rs3("IdPartida") = IdPartida
            rs3("IdFichas") = i
            rs3("IdPosicion") = x&y
            rs3("EstadoInicial") = 1
            rs3.Update
        Next
    Next    

    rs2.Update

    con.CommitTrans
```

And this BD

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

I want to fill the table Fichastablero with the IdFicha. It is to place the chips of a chessboard.. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI3nQ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7qRZ.png

This must be the result for the white chips: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEjmu.png

I'm sorry, it's my first task with .asp

Comment: Looks like your logic is off. Can you explain why you've got the `.Update` inside the loops and the `.AddNew` at the top outside of the loops? What is the desired state of the rs3 recordset upon script completion?

Comment: I want to fill the table Fichastablero with the IdFicha. It is to place the chips of a chessboard.. ////// https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI3nQ.png  ////// https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7qRZ.png

Comment: This must be the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEjmu.png

Comment: You can't put value in auto increment field. Just remove those two lines, the value should be auto populated, that's the whole point of auto increment fields.

Comment: I'm not filling the table with the automatic increment, the table Fichas(second image). I'm filling the table FichasTablero (first image), that is not incremental.

Comment: I think `rs3.OPEN SQL2,con,2,3` should be `rs3.OPEN SQL3,con,2,3`. The sql statement you have shown is `SQL3` ..

Comment: ups, thanks that was wrong. But the error keeps showing.

Comment: Can you show SQL2? Did you try changing the query from `SELECT *` to `SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM TABLE` ? If SQL2 is a typo, please update the code to reflect any changes made so far.

Comment: What's your connection string?  When you use MySQL with Classic ASP you usually connect through the MyODBC driver, which as far as I know doesn't support editable recordsets.  You might need to rewrite using Insert queries

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `SELECT * FROM FichasTablero` you will need to reference fields by ordinal NUMBERs instead of names. Here are two options:

1: Change your query to `SQL3 = "SELECT IdPartida, IdFichas, IdPosicion, EstadoInicial FROM FichasTablero WHERE 0"`

this will allow you to keep your field assignments as they are, referenced by ordinal names.

2: Change the field assignments to use ordinal numbers:

```
For x = 1 To 2
    For y = 1 To 8
        i = i+1
        Response.Write(i & "-")
        rs3(1) = i         'IdFichas
        rs3(2) = IdPartida 'IdPartida
        rs3(3) = x&y       'IdPosicion
        rs3(4) = 1         'EstadoInicial
        rs3.Update
    Next
Next

For x = 7 To 8
    For y = 1 To 8
        i = i+1
        Response.Write(i & "-")
        rs3(1) = i         'IdFichas
        rs3(2) = IdPartida 'IdPartida
        rs3(3) = x&y       'IdPosicion
        rs3(4) = 1         'EstadoInicial
        rs3.Update
    Next
Next
```

Give that a shot, good luck.